# toString() Method

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, random, tostring

How would I make this `toString()`method return melody and beats in two lines with the code I wrote below? I am not sure exactly how to incorporate the beats in the for loop:

```
public String toString(){
    String result = "";
    for (double[] level: melody){
        for (double item: level)
            result += "\n";
    }
    return result;
```

For example, what it means by two lines is it's supposed to print something that looks like this:

> 157.18 977.21 3051.07 1887.60 1339.81 182.63 984.57 2324.46
>   1.4 1.2 2.0 2.0 1.0 2.2 1.8 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to get the `Random` double in the range:

```
double rnd = new Random().nextDouble();
double result = 27.5 + (rnd * (4186.0 - 27.5));
System.out.println(result);
```

Or in the method:

```
public static double nextRandomInRange(double min, double max) {
    return min + (new Random().nextDouble() * (max - min));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code

```
Random r = new Random();
double n = 27.5 + (4186 - 27.5) * r.nextDouble();
n = (double)Math.round(n * 100) / 100;
```